# Rules in htaccess don't work or break the website

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to add the following code to my htaccess file, but, although the code comes from pages that claim that this is how these things should be done, they either don't work or they break the site.

```
# BEGIN Rewrites
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# If user asked for www.loganyoung.za.net,
# redirect to loganyoung.za.net
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.loganyoung.za.net [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://loganyoung.za.net/$1 [r=301,nc] 

# END Rewrites

# BEGIN Compress
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
```

Currently I have this code commented out so as to keep the site online.

In this case, the **Rewrite breaks the site** and the **Compression doesn't appear to work**.

I got the code from the following links:

- [Compression](http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html)
- [Redirect](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php)

With my limited knowledge/experience with htaccess, I can't see any problems here. Can someone help me to understand why these don't work and help me to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "breaks the site" HOW? you get a 500? redirected elsehwere?

Comment: @MarcB breaks the site by having the site report something about incorrect redirects. Croises answer below solved that problem, but I'm still trying to get the compression working.

Answer (score 0):

For rewrites, try uppercase with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.loganyoung\.za\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://loganyoung.za.net/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Seems like that's worked, got any input regarding the compression?

Comment: First: Are you sure that the `mod_gzip` module is installed on the server ?

Comment: I'm sure... I was using ob_start(); before on my old site and that seemed to work fine

Comment: Try with `<IfModule mod_gzip.c>absolutely anything bla bla bla</IfModule>`. If there is no server error is that the module is not enabled.